# Why Ethereum addresses contain lowercase and uppercase letters

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, eoa

Take my address for example : 0xc9d7b2e7fb30613cf0303438e739ff0aa7c856ef
You can see all of the alphabet letters are small case . But when I search this address in polygon mumbai for example , I get the following result :
[image]

Now you can see that my address looks like combination of capital letters , small letters and numbers . How this works ? I searched using small-case version ( if that's what it is called ) of my address but when I got result from the explorer , it has made some letters capitalized . How did this happened ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ethereum address checksum is encoded in alphabet cases in hexadecimal. This allows to detect copy-paste errors in Ethereum addresses.

[This is EIP-55 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-55).

Comment: Thanks Mikko , got my answer